# making responsive Gridview image with three columns

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, gridview

I have created an android application using GridView having three columns. The application is working fine but the problem is that the gridview columns are not completely filling with the view like as shown below.

[image]

In html we can put in terms of 100% to make as responsive based on resolution how can we make the same in android

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="60px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5px"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5px" />
```

**mygrid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="80px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:background="#444444" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#669966"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**mygridActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class mygridActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView g;

    Integer[] img = { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

    String[] labels = { "Android", "Calender", "Sweety's Home", "New Calender",
            "Home", "Star", "GTalk", "Mick", "No Entry" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Pic : " + (arg2 + 1), 1)
                        .show();
            }
        });

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context mGrid;

        public ImageAdapter(Context g) {
            this.mGrid = g;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return img.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = new View(mGrid);
                LayoutInflater Inf = getLayoutInflater();
                view = Inf.inflate(R.layout.mygrid, null);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            iv.setImageResource(img[position]);
            tv.setText(labels[position]);
            return view;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the complete layout file of the mygrid.xml?

Comment: @ShadowDroid I have posted

Answer (score 2):

Please add the gravity to views within linear layout make it as center rather just making only TextView as center

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center">
 //your code
</LinearLayout>
```

**Updates Based on comments**
To understand difference between dip/dp and px you can check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension   and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence  
Alternativley you can specify width and height in dimens.xml and values-sw720dp/dimens.xml for mobile and tablet respectively

 To handle multiple screen please follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: how can I change the ImageView widh and height as in terms of percentage since, If I run this application in tablet the image seems to be very small

Comment: do not use pixels rather go for dp for width and height...check this https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/  it will help you

Comment: can you give me a sample dimens.xml for mobile and tablet based on my given code

Comment: First tell whether problem you mentioned in the question is solved or not...and would like to know the configuration of the tablet

Comment: Yes problem is solved, it would be good if you can tell me the dimens.xml for tablet and mobile

Comment: can you tell me the dimens.xml

Comment: @Alex please check the following link http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/appendix-c-everything-about-sizes-and-dimensions-in-android/ even if you are not able to understand then I will post the updated answer. If you are asking me what value should be present...then for that check your requirement